# Laravel TCP Server to accept incoming data

Tags: php, laravel

So basically up until now I've always used Laravel with API routes - i.e. I accept incoming data through the API and direct it to controller and service to process it and save it in my DB hosted on GoDaddy.

Now, I've got a device which makes use of a TCP connection in order to send data and so I'd need to host a TCP Server from my Laravel project. Is this possible? I've found this [guide](https://www.techalyst.com/posts/php-and-laravel-receiving-gps-tracker-data-to-specific-tcpip-port) but I wouldn't want to run the script each time but rather my Laravel framework automatically sets up the TCP server and accept the incoming data which I can then process etc. Just like an API route is 'automated' i.e. directed to a controller, I'd like something similar for a TCP connection (if it is possible).

Thanks

Comment: If I correctly understand your question, you won't be able to use Laravel as a TCP server. Laravel it's a framework based on PHP which runs on a server. And in the server there's installed Apache or Tomcat or whatever engine able to process your HTTP request sent from TCP. So, basically, you need to look for an engine that runs on server, not for a framework

Comment: Hmmm you're right. Any idea of an engine that would do that? I'd ideally be looking at a good guide which I can follow.

Comment: Take a look at [this comparison table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_server_software). Note that the most used are Apache, Tomcat and Nginx.
If you are looking for an all-in-one solution you can take a look at [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) and all of it's platform-specific variants: MAMP for Mac and LAMPP for Linux-based systems (avoid WAMP because it's deprecated and no more maintained)

Comment: Sorry to bother again, right now on GoDaddy I've got an Apache HTTP Server. Probably that won't be enough in order to handle raw TCP connections right?

Comment: Apache and all the servers I mentioned are WEB server: they are meant to handle web-related protocols such as HTTP and HTTPS. If you need a protocol-specific engine you'll have to google a bit to find what you need. But, since you use Laravel, I think web servers are enough for your needs. Don't get confused and mix data carried by protocols with protocols themself. Protocols are, roughly, the way the client must send data and the way the server must respond; but data are, in a way, independent from protocols

Comment: Yes right, however I'm not sure how to handle the socket connections from Laravel then i.e. I found a guide about setting up websockets but to setup the TCP socket then you'd need to run the script. Ideally that would be the server's job - handle an incoming TCP connection and direct it to a script.

Comment: To directly answer to your question, no, you cannot handle raw TCP connections unless you write your own server in, e.g., C , C++, Python or whatever language you like. You can take a look at [this article](https://pymotw.com/2/socket/tcp.html) to start with a server

Comment: Hi Matteo, thank you for that once again. Do you recommend a framework for this perhaps? Since I'm accustomed to Laravel I'd prefer to use it instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208496/discussion-between-matteo-meil-and-luke-galea).